# Question about a step in a proof about surjection and cardinality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Statement:

> Let $f: S \to T$ be surjective with $|S| = n$. Then $|T| \le n.$

Proof (slightly paraphrased for shortness):

> Let $x \in T$. By WOP $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ has a least element as $f^{-1}(\{x\}) \subseteq S \subseteq \mathbb N.$ Define $g: T \to S$ as $g(x)$ is the smallest element in $f^{-1}(\{x\})$. Now $g(x) \in f^{-1}(\{x\}) \implies f(g(x)) = x$ meaning $f\circ g = I_T. \ \color{red}{ \text{By the fact that identity mapping is bijection, $I_T: T \to g(T)$ is bijection}}.$ Thus $|T| = |g(T)| \le n$ as $g(T) \subseteq S.$

Slightly confused about the part in red above. I think $I_T$ is a map from $T$ to $T$. How is it related to $I_T: T \to g(T)?$

I read the proof on

[Cardinality of Surjection](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_Surjection)

Comment: $I_T$ is the compositum of $g$ and $f$: it is the result of applying $g$ first, and then applying $f$, as stated in the immediately prior sentence: “meaning that $f\circ g=I_T$. Note that $f\circ g$ is a function from $T$ to $T$, as well. $I_T$ does not go $T\to g(T)$, it goes $T$ to $T$. But what you are doing is $T\stackrel{g}{\to}g(T)\stackrel{f}{\to}T$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, so, did the author mean to say $f\circ g = I_T \implies g: T \to g(T)$ is also identity?

Comment: It's saying that $g(T)$ is a subset of $S$ that is in one-to-one correspondence with $T$.  Thus $T$ must have fewer things than $S$.

Comment: No, the author meant to say exactly what they said. $g$ is a function, not an identity. If a composition is one-to-one, then the first function is one-to-one, so you know that $g$ is one-to-one, which means that $|T|=|g(T)|$, which is all you need to proceed.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I see. No more questions. Thanks.